# Looking one char ahead when reading from file in C

Tags: c, file, loops

I am aware that in c there are functions getc() and ungetc().

I would need this counter-function for fgetc(), sadly unfgetc() doesn't really exist. So I tried writting it on my own.

This is how it looks:

```
    int getNextChar(FILE* fd)
{
    // get the character
    int nextCharacter = fgetc(fd);

    // fseek it back, so you don't really move the file descriptor
    fseek(fd, -1, SEEK_CUR);

    // returning the char (as int)
    return nextCharacter;
}
```

But well... that doesn't seem to work. 
I call it inside a while loop, like this.

```
while ( (c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF)
    {

        cx = getNextChar(fd);
        printf("%c", c);


    }
```

It gets stucked on the last character of the file (it prints it with every iteration to infinity). Now a little explanation why I need that in case that I'm doing it all wrong and that there would be another suitable solution.

I need to check the next character on being EOF. If it is EOF, I force send token, that is created in the while loop (this part is not important for my issue, so I didnt include it).

I am going through the loop and whenever I find a character that doesnt respond to a mask, I assume that I should send a token and start making a new one with that character that doesnt respond. Naturally, when I read the last char in the file, no next iteration will be done, therefore I won't send the last token. I need to check next char to be EOF. If it is EOF, I force send token.

Thank you for your advices!

Comment: `getc` and `fgetc` are not very different (`getc` might be a macro, while `fgetc` must be a function, but both do the same thing.) `ungetc` will work with `fgetc` with either of them. `fseek`, on the other hand, will only work with regular files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check that `nextCharacter` isn't `EOF`, since if it is, you'll still back off, thus causing the outer reading to never see the end of the file. Also check return values of more functions, like `fseek()`.